# Check for running MIJ instances

Tags: java, matlab, instance, imagej

In Matlab I am using MIJ to interact with ImageJ. Is there a way (matlab command) to check if an instance of ImageJ is already been created via MIJ.start(...) command? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [MIJ source code](http://bigwww.epfl.ch/sage/soft/mij/MIJ.java): you should be able to test if `MIJ.imagej` is currently null. If so, ImageJ has not been started yet via MIJ.